# missing view file with ajax post method

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have trying to filter record form database in cakephp. I am using ajax post method to fetch details on same page.But error is missing view file .Here is my controller .

```
public function userfunddetails(){
        $this->autoLayout = false;  
        $userid = $this->request->data('userid');
        $startdate = $this->request->data('startdate');
        $startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startdate));
        $enddate = $this->request->data('enddate');
        $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($enddate));
        $conditions = array(
        array('Recharge.add_date >= ' => $startdate, 'Recharge.add_date <=' => $enddate),
            'Recharge.user_id =' => $userid
            );
        $data = $this->Recharge->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions));
        $this->set('data', $data);   
    }
```

And here is my ajax code . Same thing working on with other function.
I do not know what happen .But same code working for other module.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#frm_rechargeHistory_process').submit(function(){
    var userid = $("#userid").val();
    var startdate = $("#startdate").val();
    //alert(startdate);
   // var startdate = new Date($('#startdate').val());
    //var startdate = $("#startdate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' }).val();
   // var enddate = $("#enddate").val();   // Call ajax for pass data to other place
    //var enddate = new Date($('#enddate').val());
    var enddate = $("#enddate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' }).val();
  // alert(enddate);
    var dataString = 'userid='+ userid + '&startdate='+ startdate + '&enddate='+ enddate;
    if(userid==''||startdate==''||enddate=='')
    {
    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    }else
    {
    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "userfunddetails",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
    //alert(result);
    $('#txtHint').html(result);
    }
    });
    }
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check, If it is helpful for you.

In this case,there are two options:

First, you can create the ctp file here: YOURCONROLLER/userfunddetails.ctp and use the $data array.

OR

Second you can put json_encode() in your controller function like below and put die() at the end of function.

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('data' => $data)); die; ?>
```

You can found the $data array in your jquery response.

Comment: Mohit Mathur@{"data":[{"Recharge":{"id":"33","api_id":"1","user_id":"41","mobile_no":"8604496604","type":false,"operator":"12","amount":"10","request_time":"2018-11-13 07:47:39","response_time":"2018-11-13 07:47:40","status":"PENDING","description":"PENDING","api_response_code":"PENDING","ip":"208.91.199.100","transaction_no":"49d3da8b54","comm_type":"0","commission":"2.9","comm_amount":"0","extra_1":"","extra_2":"","extra_3":"","extra_4":"","extra_5":"","add_date":"2018-11-13 07:47:39"}}@ I need only object value it's showing json array

Comment: Mohit Mathur@I need api_id value mobile number it's return key and value here.

Comment: Mohit Mathur
@you there

Comment: var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
alert(obj['api_id'])
use this.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call looks for the URL "userHistorydetails" while your function is named "userfunddetails".

Also, shouldn't you use "/controller/userfunddetails" as URL?

Comment: proprit@I renamed